# $\operatorname{tr}((AB)^m)\leq (\operatorname{tr}(AB))^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$I'm trying to understand the following proof: $\tr((AB)^m)\leq (\tr(AB))^m$ for $A>0$ and $B>0$.

proof: The equality holds for $m=1$. For $m>1$, Let $B=I$ and $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. Since $\sum_i\lambda_i^m<(\sum_i\lambda_i)^m$, we see 
$$
0<\tr(A)<(\tr(A))^m \tag 1
$$
Since $(1)$ is true for any $A>0$, let $D=B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$. Then $(1)$ holds for $D$. Thus, $0<\tr(D^m)<(\tr(D))^m$, from which the result follows.

I can see why $(1)$ applies to $D$ if $A$ and $B$ commute, but if they don't commute, I don't see why this is true. Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: @Yikai Yes, $>$ means positive definite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that inequality $(1)$ holds for any positive definite matrix $A$. Observe also that $B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ is positive definite since
$B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$ is symmetric and for any vector $x \neq 0$, we have
$$
x^TB^{1/2}AB^{1/2}x = (B^{1/2}x)^TA(B^{1/2}x) > 0
$$
Therefore, $(1)$ can be applied to $D = B^{1/2}AB^{1/2}$.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what my mistake was. I was thinking I needed to show $D^m=(AB)^m$, which is true if $A$ and $B$ commute, but not necessarily if they don't. But even if they don't the commutativity of $tr$ fixes this I think. Thanks for you answer.